# Two train, of same length, are running in parallel tracks

Tags: geometry

Two train , of same length, are running in parallel tracks in opposite directions with speed 65km/h and 85 km/h respectively. They cross each other in 6 sec. The length of each train is?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Your question will not be well received if we don't see that you've put some effort into solving this problem on your own.  For starters: try putting yourself in the perspective of the conductor of the train going $65 km/h$.  How fast is the other train going *relative* to you?

Answer (score 1):

Put your self in the seat of the conductor of one of the trains. From your point of view (your moving reference frame), you see your train as stationary.

What is the observed speed of the other train?

You see this other train at $v_{obs}$ move past you in 6 seconds. (Not quite sure on the wording, do they mean mean one train passes a point on the other in 6 sec or time from front-to-front to back-to-back? If the former is the correct interpretation....) You now have $\Delta t$ and $v$. What is $\Delta x$?